# vba 1004 application undefined or application defined error?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which I am running to control the behaviour of a form in excel, when a user clicks submit this sends two emails and resets some values and formulas in the cells on my worksheet. however when this runs I get a 1004 error application undefined or application defined error and I don't know why this is?

Can someone please help me find the cause of the problem.

the part of the code affected I believe is:

```
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim DestRow As Long
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Home")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Statistics")

     ws1.Range("B10").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("B15").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("B20").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("H10").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("H15").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("H20").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("N10").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$F$1:$F$10004,MATCH(H20,'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)),"")"
     ws1.Range("N15").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$H$1:$H$10004,MATCH(H20,'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)),"")"
     ws1.Range("B32").Formula = "=IF(C32=""Yes"",B34,IF(ISTEXT(B10),CONCATENATE(""NS"")&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9),""""))"
     ws1.Range("B34").Formula = "=IF(C34 <>""Yes"",B32,B34)"
     ws1.Range("N20").Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(B10),NOW(),"""")"
     ws1.Range("H32").Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(B10),""Awaiting Manager Approval"","""")"
     ws1.Range("N32").Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(B10),""Request to be Reviewed"","""")"



    Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'Set the message box to close after 10 seconds
    AckTime = 1
    Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Thank You" & vbNewLine & "Your request has been successfully submitted.", _
    AckTime, "Thank You", 0)
        Case 1, -1
    End Select


End If
End If
End Sub
```

Heres all my code together.

Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If Target.Column = Range("Z1").Column And Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "SUBMIT" Then
If Range("B10").Value = "" Or Range("B15").Value = "" Or Range("B20").Value = "" Or Range("H10").Value = "" Or Range("H15").Value = "" Or Range("H20").Value = "" Or Range("N10").Value = "" Or Range("N15").Value = "" Or Range("N20").Value = "" Then
Dim AckTime As Integer, InfoBox As Object
    Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'Set the message box to close after 10 seconds
    AckTime = 1
    Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Ooops!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "We can't submit this form," & vbNewLine & "you did not complete all the required information.", _
    AckTime, "Cannot Submit the Form!", 0)
        Case 1, -1
    End Select

ElseIf Target.Column = Range("Z1").Column And Range("Z" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "SUBMIT" And Range("B10").Value <> "" Then

Dim AckTime2 As Integer, InfoBox2 As Object
    Set InfoBox2 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'Set the message box to close after 10 seconds
    AckTime2 = 1
    Select Case InfoBox2.Popup("Please Wait" & vbNewLine & "We are dealing with your request.", _
    AckTime2, "Please Wait", 0)
        Case 1, -1
    End Select

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    TempFilePath = "\\UKSH000-File06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\"

    strbody = "<p style='color:#000;font-family:calibri;font-size:16'>Dear Purchasing Admin," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "This is an automated email, sent to you from New Suppliers." & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "You have a New Supplier Set-Up Request. Please find the details of the application listed below:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><b>" & "Company Name: " & "</b>" & Range("B10").Value & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><b>" & "Company Number: " & "</b>" & Range("B15").Value & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><b>" & "Case Reference: " & "</b>" & Range("B32").Value & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><b>" & "Description of the provisional Supplier: " & "</b>" & "<br>" & Range("B20").Value & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><b>" & "Current Status: " & "</b>" & Range("Y7").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><b>" & "Request By: " & "</b>" & Range("H15").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><b>" & "Allocated Manager: " & "</b>" & Range("N10").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><b>" & "Allocated Depot " & "</b>" & Range("N15").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><br>" & "Note:" & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "Please keep a note of your reference number in the event you should have any enquiries. All enquiries should be emailed to NewSuppliers@Hewden.co.uk and you should quote your reference number." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "Kind Regards," & "</font></p>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<p style='color:#000;font-family:calibri;font-size:18'><b>Automated Purchasing Email</font></p></b>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><img src='cid:cover.jpg'" & "width='800' height='64'><br>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<img src='cid:subs.jpg'" & "width='274' height='51'>"


    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "newsuppliers@hewden.co.uk"
        .To = "newsuppliers@hewden.co.uk"
        .CC = "supplieraudits@hewden.co.uk"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "New Supplier Request - Reference: " & Range("B32").Value & ""
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "cover.jpg", olByValue, 0
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "subs.jpg", olByValue, 0
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .send   'or use .Display
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    TempFilePath = "\\UKSH000-File06\Purchasing\New_Supplier_Set_Ups_&_Audits\assets\"

    strbody = "<p style='color:#000;font-family:calibri;font-size:16'>Dear " & Range("H15").Value & "," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "This is an automated email, sent to you by the purchasing department." & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "This is to confirm that we have successfully received your New Supplier Set-Up Request. Whilst we endeavour to complete your supplier request within 3-5 days, please allow upto 10 days for this process to be compelted, the process can be delayed if information is missing or incomplete. That's it for now, you don't need to do anything else, we are carrying out some checks on this supplier and will gather the information we need. We will keep you up to date on the status of your New Supplier Request by email. Please see the information below for your reference." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><b>" & "Supplier Name: " & "</b>" & Range("B10").Value & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><b>" & "Case Reference Number: " & "</b>" & Range("B32").Value & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><b>" & "Supplier Status: " & "</b>" & Range("Y7").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "Note:" & vbNewLine & _
              "<br>" & "Please keep a note of your reference number in the event you should have any enquiries. All enquiries should be emailed to NewSuppliers@Hewden.co.uk and you should quote your reference number." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br>" & "Kind Regards," & "</font></p>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<p style='color:#000;font-family:calibri;font-size:18'><b>Automated Purchasing Email</font></p></b>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<br><br><img src='cid:cover.jpg'" & "width='800' height='64'><br>" & vbNewLine & _
              "<img src='cid:subs.jpg'" & "width='274' height='51'>"


    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "newsuppliers@hewden.co.uk"
        .To = Range("H22").Value
        .CC = "supplieraudits@hewden.co.uk"
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "New Supplier Request - Reference: " & Range("B32").Value & ""
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "cover.jpg", olByValue, 0
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "subs.jpg", olByValue, 0
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .send   'or use .Display
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False



    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim DestRow As Long
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Home")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Statistics")

     ws1.Range("B10").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("B15").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("B20").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("H10").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("H15").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("H20").Value = ""
     ws1.Range("N10").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$F$1:$F$10004,MATCH(H20,'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)),"")"
     ws1.Range("N15").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$H$1:$H$10004,MATCH(H20,'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)),"")"
     ws1.Range("B32").Formula = "=IF(C32=""Yes"",B34,IF(ISTEXT(B10),CONCATENATE(""NS"")&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9)&RANDBETWEEN(0,9),""""))"
     ws1.Range("B34").Formula = "=IF(C34 <>""Yes"",B32,B34)"
     ws1.Range("N20").Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(B10),NOW(),"""")"
     ws1.Range("H32").Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(B10),""Awaiting Manager Approval"","""")"
     ws1.Range("N32").Formula = "=IF(ISTEXT(B10),""Request to be Reviewed"","""")"



    Set InfoBox = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'Set the message box to close after 10 seconds
    AckTime = 1
    Select Case InfoBox.Popup("Thank You" & vbNewLine & "Your request has been successfully submitted.", _
    AckTime, "Thank You", 0)
        Case 1, -1
    End Select


End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which object did you add that made this error appear?

Comment: If you click "Debug" when you get the error, which line get highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your Excel Formulas:

```
ws1.Range("N10").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$F$1:$F$10004,MATCH(H20,'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)),"")"
```

You have quotation marks inside of your quotation marks. VBA is seeing:
`"=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$F$1:$F$10004,MATCH(H20,'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)),"` and `")"` and has no idea why you would stick them next to each other. You'll need to either use a character code `chr(34)` for your inner quotation marks, or double them so they are properly escaped

```
ws1.Range("N10").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$F$1:$F$10004,MATCH(H20,'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)), " & chr(34) & chr(34) & ")"
```

or

```
ws1.Range("N10").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX('Depot Data'!$F$1:$F$10004,MATCH(H20,'Depot Data'!$E$1:$E$10004,0)),"""")"
```